# How does tf.layers create variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Everytime we call `tf.layers.conv2d`, Tensorflow will automatically creates new kernel, bias and new name for this tensor by adding `_1`, `_2`, like:

```
<tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 10, 10) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'conv2d/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 10, 10) dtype=float32_ref>,  
<tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>
conv2d/BiasAdd:0
conv2d_1/BiasAdd:0
```

If I would like to define a similar layer with variables inside, for example,

```
def some_layer(input):
    gamma = tf.get_variable(name='gamma', shape=[10], dtype=tf.float32,
                        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0))

x = some_layer(input)
y = some_layer(input)
```

It will cause `ValueError: Variable gamma already exists`. I know there are methods to give each variable a name scope or variable scope, but I am wondering is there any method to automatically create new variables `gamma_1:0`, `gamma_2:0` like `conv2d/kernel:0`, `conv2d_1/kernel:0` after calling `tf.layers.conv2d`.

The [definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py) of `tf.layers.conv2d` gives me no hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tensorflow tutorial [custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_layers) gives the answer. If we need to build a custom layer, we will need to extend the class `tf.keras.layers.Layer`.